# Activiti Task Not Created in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I'm building a review and approve workflow where the reviewer and the task assignee should be able to exchange message from the tasks' forms,  the problem is that when the task is not being recreated if the reviewer hits the reject button, the create listener is not being called when the execution is returned to this task, is there any way to force alfresco to recreate a task every time it is reached?

Update: 
the problem happens in the following embedded sub-process,

```
<subProcess id="subprocess3" name="Sub Process">
        <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false" activiti:collection="${swwf_splitAssignees}" activiti:elementVariable="splitAssignee"></multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
        <userTask id="splittedDelegatedTask" name="DelegatedTask" activiti:assignee="${splitAssignee.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="swwf:splittedDelegatedTask">
          <extensionElements>
            <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="com.smartway_me.translation_amp.listeners.delegatedTaskCreatedListener"></activiti:taskListener>
            <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener"> 
                <activiti:field name="script">
                    <activiti:string>
                        execution.setVariableLocal('swwf_messageToSplitter',task.getVariable('swwf_messageToSplitter'))
                        execution.setVariableLocal('swwf_delegatedMessage',task.getVaraible('swwf_messageToSplitter'))
                    </activiti:string>
                </activiti:field>
            </activiti:taskListener>
          </extensionElements>
        </userTask>
        <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="splittedDelegatedTask" targetRef="splitterReview"></sequenceFlow>
        <userTask id="splitterReview" name="SplitterReview" activiti:assignee="${inAssignee.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="swwf:splitterReview">
          <extensionElements>
            <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="com.smartway_me.translation_amp.listeners.DelegatorReviewTaskCreateListener"></activiti:taskListener>
            <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="com.smartway_me.translation_amp.listeners.DelegatorReviewTaskCompleteListener"></activiti:taskListener>
          </extensionElements>
        </userTask>
        <sequenceFlow id="flow6" sourceRef="splitterReview" targetRef="exclusivegateway2"></sequenceFlow>
        <exclusiveGateway id="exclusivegateway2" name="Exclusive Gateway"></exclusiveGateway>
        <sequenceFlow id="flow7" sourceRef="exclusivegateway2" targetRef="splittedDelegatedTask">
          <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${swwf_splitterReviewOutcome=='Reject'}]]></conditionExpression>
        </sequenceFlow>
        <sequenceFlow id="flow20" sourceRef="exclusivegateway2" targetRef="endevent3">
          <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${swwf_splitterReviewOutcome=='Approve'}]]></conditionExpression>
        </sequenceFlow>
        <endEvent id="endevent3" name="End"></endEvent>
        <startEvent id="startevent3" name="Start"></startEvent>
        <sequenceFlow id="flow36" sourceRef="startevent3" targetRef="splittedDelegatedTask"></sequenceFlow>
      </subProcess>
```

Comment: would you mind posting your bpmn file ?

Comment: the bpm file is rather big, I updated the question with the sub-process in which I'm facing this problem.

Comment: try checking this feature: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnMultiInstance I guess it enables you to create a new instance of your task each time you reach it, I am not sure though, you need to do some experiments !

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help. I managed to find another solution, I stored the task id of the task to be reviewed and used it through TaskService to access the task and modify its variables